# Can I put custom comments when recommend a deletion of an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I had a lot of situations where I need to put  "*my own*" comment when recommend a deletion of an answer. This is because, I felt none of the available options do not suit to indicate the real problem in the answer.

For an example, recently I came to recommend deletion of an answer that seems like this

```
I got it now. Google is your friend!
```

One of our community member answered his own question like this ! There were no better suit deletion option available when I recommended this answer for deletion.

It would be nice if there was an option to put a custom comment while recommend for deletion.

So my questions are..

Is there any provision to do that ?

If not, why it is not available ?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, not sure if that what you mean but there's always an "other" item while flagging where you can put your reason.